# How to create a Glitch shader?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, shaders

I´d like to create a glitch texture shader using Cycles.
Most of my searches on google have resulted in failure since the word "glitch" is associated with real life malfunctioning of cycles.

In turn, I´d like to know what could be the appropiate steps to deform a texture using the new voronoi node plus bricks node to offset in X-Y-Z rgb values a texture or a color so we could create a glitch effect.

Thanks.

Comment: Glitch is a bit ambiguous. What do you define as a glitch? Best to add some images to show what you mean.

Comment: I searched for 'blender glitch node setup' and got plenty of results. 
I'm not sure how you want to archive a glitch with cycles nodes? Because I define it as a digital or analog video failure (glitch). 
So the results using the compositor to add a glitch effect to the whole render/image.

Comment: Glitch, like in video copilot glitch effects.

Comment: So far I know I want to use the brick texture and the vertex modify weights modifier. I hope to pull out something soon. The tutorials you´re probably refering has to deal with the VSE. I´m talking about actual displacement of the mesh.